# Remote Desktop Shadow session/user info via PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

Is there a way to query the system in PS for the ID of the person in the [shadow mode](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2013/10/22/windows-8-1-windows-server-2012-r2-rds-shadowing-is-back/) or the ID's of everyone connected and the type of their connections and connection start times.

(Working on Windows Server 2012R2 and 2016)

I'd like to avoid querying for the specific event log Event ID's and I've already tried these without any success:

- query user /server:$SERVER
- qwinsta
- query session
- query termserver
- Get-RDUserSession
- Get-RDUserSession | ft Username, UnifiedSessionId, SessionState, HostServer, ApplicationType -GroupBy Sessionstate